# unable to retrieve data from User table parse.com

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I want to retrieve all data from user table and show it in listView when user is loged in. For that i am using ListFragment in main activity i also created User class to defined getter and setter function as it is recommended in parse.com
Problem is when i run my app it doesn't show any data neither it gives me any error.

This is User table at parse.com
[image]

Here code for my User class.

```
@ParseClassName("User")
public class User extends ParseObject {

public User(){}

public  String getUsername(){
    return getString("username");
}
public void setUsername(String username){
    put("username",username);
}

public  String getLatitude(){
    return getString("Latitude");
}
public void setLatitude(String latitude){
    put("Latitude",latitude);
}
public String getLongitude(){
    return getString("Longitude");
}
public void setLongitude(String longitude){
    put("Longitude",longitude);
}
public void setBloodType(String bloodType){put("Bloodtype",bloodType);}
public String getBloodType(){return getString("Bloodtpye");}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getString("username") + "\n" + getString("Longitude") + "\n" + getString("Latitude")+ "\n"+getString("Bloodtype");
}
}
```

Here code of my fragment

```
 public class Fragment extends ListFragment {

List<User> user1 = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ParseQuery<User> query = new ParseQuery<User>("User");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<User> list, ParseException e) {
            if(e !=null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                for (User user : list){
                    User newUser = new User();
                    newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
                    newUser.setLatitude(user.getLatitude());
                    newUser.setLongitude(user.getLongitude());
                    newUser.setBloodType(user.getBloodType());
                    user1.add(newUser);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,user1);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Help me

ok i played around my code and i changed the code of query now it gives me some result. Check this screenshot

[image]

updated code for query is here

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                for (ParseUser user :list){
                    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("username"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Latitude"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Longitude"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Bloodtype"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Mobile"));
                    user1.add(newUser);

                }
                ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ParseUser>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,user1);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: it doesn't give any error

Comment: Can you tell me if it is right way to retrieve data from User table?

Comment: does it return an empty list?

Comment: do u know how to create a custom adapter for the listview?

Comment: vishnus i am new to android programming. No i don't know

Comment: is there toString() method in your changed class ParseUser?

Comment: ok.. so so ull need to learn about it because the problem is with your ArrayAdapter implementation. Follow this tutorial http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview

Comment: Yes there is i have overwriten it

Comment: Yes i will go throught custom adapter. Can you tell me what is problem there?

Comment: the problem is that the default toString() method of any class does not return the description u desire and the array adapter by default displays the value returned by toString() method

Comment: Or as Vitaly has said, it can be done by overriding toString() method in ur ParseUser class. e.g. If u just want to display the username in the list then just "return getString("username")" add this code to toString() method of ur ParseUser class

Comment: can you suggest me a quick solution to this problem? Sorry actually i have less time. have to done it in 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with the accessibility of your objects. You should play around with ParseACL.

Default ACLs make it easy to create apps that follow common access patterns. An application like Twitter, for example, where user content is generally visible to the world, might set a default ACL such as:

```
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

For an application like Dropbox, where a user's data is only accessible by the user itself unless explicit permission is given, you would provide a default ACL where only the current user is given access:

```
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(new ParseACL(), true);
```

An application that logs data to Parse but doesn't provide any user access to that data would instead deny access to the current user while providing a restrictive ACL:

```
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(new ParseACL(), false);
```

look at https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Comment: Tried that nothing happens.

Comment: Kindly go through my question again. I have updated it now. It is returning me some weird stuff

Comment: Solution lies in Custom adapter. I have solved it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

Make User extend ParseUser instead of ParseObject.

```
public class User extends ParseUser
```

and use the old code for setting the adapter i.e.

```
else {
            for (User user : list){
                User newUser = new User();
                newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
                newUser.setLatitude(user.getLatitude());
                newUser.setLongitude(user.getLongitude());
                newUser.setBloodType(user.getBloodType());
                user1.add(newUser);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,user1);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

I hope this helps. Cheers :)